# Need to stop Startapp Splash Ad

Tags: android-studio, sdk, splash-screen, startapp

I need to disable startup splash Ad

`StartAppAd.disableSplash()`

And I added the following code in my app activities, but after adding its showing error  "cannot resolve symbol"   I have to disable splash ad. Anybody can help

Answer (score 0):

better if you post your detailed error in logcat. so everyone can understand your error code

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're using the latest version of StartApp dependency

```
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    // noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:4.8.+'
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create a class App and call StartAppAd.disableSplash();

```
import com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.StartAppAd;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        StartAppAd.disableSplash();
    }
}
```

add in manifests

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
```